# JSoup doesn't retrieve JSON data from script tag

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get content inside a script tag (JSON data) from a recipe in an HTML page, using JSoup (1.13.1). I won't post the HTML code but the script tag content is pretty big.

Whenever I try to print the content, I get an empty string. I tried to get my data using different methods: by selecting the ID `doc.select("#__NEXT_DATA__")`, or by using `doc.select("script[type='application/json']")`

If I try to iterate through all the script tags, whenever it gets to the script tag I want, it prints blank.
I also tried to print the content using `text()` method and the `toString()` method but it doesn't work. I even saw someone saying you could set the `maxBodySize(0)` but it still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
String url = "https://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_gateau-au-chocolat-fondant-rapide_166352.aspx";
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).maxBodySize(0).get();

Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#__NEXT_DATA__");
                    
for (Element element : newsHeadlines) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the script element as data:

```
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#__NEXT_DATA__");

for (Element element : newsHeadlines) {
    System.out.println(element.data());
}
```

Note that some consoles may have an issue displaying a line of 81206 characters in length (eclipse did for me) (or there was something in the data) so this code simply prints out the beginning...

```
    for (Element element : newsHeadlines) {
        System.out.println(element.data().length());
        
        int printLen = Math.min(100, element.data().length());
        System.out.println(element.data().substring(0,printLen));
    }
```

And produces:

```
81206
{"props":{"pageProps":{"recipeData":{"recipe":{"id":166352,"guid":"7bf48b95-4cd2-4b32-8f41-fb6168510
```

Note if you can use a debugger in your environment it would show that the element had the result all along but as a `childNode` of `element` of type `DataNode` which is the first clue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your solution except I didn't iterate through a for loop and just got the ```first()``` element. It was working just fine a few hours earlier but it's simply not working right now. I checked the website and apparently the script tag containing the data disappeared. Do you know any reasons for that?

Comment: I too now notice that while the `__NEXT_DATA__` script tag is still present, its data is `{}` (length=2).  This script tag apparently is produced by their React Js implementation and would not be a Jsoup question but one of their React Js implementation.  Odd thing is in some attempts using a Chrome browser (but not all) I can still see the fully populated tag.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup doesn't actually parse the script tags. When it scrapes the website, it takes the HTML source of the website BEFORE any Javascript scripts play their part. So, when you try to get the scripts, it doesn't recognize the script tags.

For this case, you might want to try another API, such as [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup's text() returns the text that would have been rendered in a browser, sort of. A 'script' tag won't render at all (unless you use CSS tricks!), so it returns an empty string. At least I think that's what Jsoup's developer/s were thinking.

Instead, what you can do is use the html() method, which returns some sort of 'raw' text, IOW the text inside the script element.